# Adding parameters to SQL select and using them in Cognos Report Studio Version 10.2.1

Tags: sql, db2, cognos, cognos-10

I'm trying to put into my select a date parameter. I'm not sure how really to do this. Right now I have fixed date value in it and now I want to have a parameter like: StartDate and EndDate.
I'll be really grateful for any help.
My select:

```
select laborcode,
(select sum(workhours) from workperiod where calnum='...'and workdate between to_date('01.02.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date('01.03.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')) -  
(select count(calnum) from workperiod where calnum='...'and workdate between to_date('01.02.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date('01.03.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') and shiftnum='HOLIDAY') * 8 as alias,
(select sum(lt.regularhrs) from labtrans lt where lt.laborcode = l.laborcode and lt.orgid = l.orgid and startdate between to_date('01.02.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date('01.03.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')) as alias,
(select sum(ass.laborhrs) from assignment ass where ass.laborcode = l.laborcode and ass.scheduledate between to_date('01.02.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date('01.03.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')) as alias
from labor l
```

Comment: that's what i meant yes..okey thanks

Comment: sorry I'm new here on stack and obviously have few mistakes in my post..thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro prompt syntax is #prompt('StartDate','date')#  Which would change your SQL to:

select laborcode,
(select sum(workhours) from workperiod where calnum='KOPA'and workdate between to_date(#prompt('StartDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date(#prompt('EndDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY')) -
(select count(calnum) from workperiod where calnum='KOPA'and workdate between to_date(#prompt('StartDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date(#prompt('EndDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY') and shiftnum='HOLIDAY') * 8 as stevilo_praznikov_ure,
(select sum(lt.regularhrs) from labtrans lt where lt.laborcode = l.laborcode and lt.orgid = l.orgid and startdate between to_date(#prompt('StartDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date(#prompt('EndDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY')) as delovne_ure,
(select sum(ass.laborhrs) from assignment ass where ass.laborcode = l.laborcode and ass.scheduledate between to_date(#prompt('StartDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date(#prompt('EndDate','date')#,'DD.MM.YYYY')) as assignment_ure
from labor l

Comment: thanks for your answer Daniel :) so if I u understand this right...i need just this select now and then use it in Cognos SQL and create parameters StartDate and EndDate?

Comment: It'll probably be native SQL but the approach would be the same.

Comment: Hey @DanielWagemann it's me again...hope you can help me here with my problem. I added the SQL and those two parameters and then when I run the report I get a error: sqlScrollBulkFetch' status='-51                                                           
UDA-SQL-0144 Odkrito je bilo aritmetično izjemno stanje.[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL20448N "2007" cannot be interpreted using format string "DD.MM.YYYY" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function. SQLSTATE=22007          Is it something wrong with the format of the parameter? 
A fully arithmetic state was detected...that's the translation above.

Comment: The driver probably does not like the date to date manipulation,  does it work if you take the to_date out?  Or you could try changing the the prompt macro data type from date to timestamp.